# Missing pagination styles in Swiperjs element (when using React with create-react-app)

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, styling, swiper.js

I'm using Swiperjs and React, I'm using the element (web component) version. I'm having issues getting the styling to work correctly but have managed to load the base styles for the "coverflow" effect.

This is the code for the component I'm working on:

```js
import React, { HTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import 'swiper/bundle';
import { register, SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types/swiper-options';

register();

// Satisfy children types.
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'swiper-container': React.DetailedHTMLProps<
                SwiperOptions & HTMLAttributes<unknown>,
                HTMLElement
            >;
            'swiper-slide': React.DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<unknown>, HTMLElement>;
        }
    }
}

export interface ICoverFlowProps {
}

export const CoverFlow: React.FC<ICoverFlowProps> = (props) => {
    const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperContainer>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!swiperRef.current) {
            return;
        }

        // Register Swiper web component
        register();

        // Object with parameters
        const params: SwiperOptions = {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            speed: 500,
            effect: 'coverflow',
            pagination: true,
        };

        // Assign it to swiper element
        Object.assign(swiperRef.current, params);

        // initialize swiper
        setTimeout(() => swiperRef.current?.initialize());
    }, [swiperRef]);

    return (
        <swiper-container ref={swiperRef} init={false}>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
    );
};
```

The pagination is inserted into the DOM but completely unstyled, the coverflow effect is working and the styling is loaded but only if swiper is imported using `import 'swiper/bundle';`. Importing the overflow styling separately seems not to work.

```js
import 'swiper/css';
// No (coverflow) styling applied once loaded like this.
import 'swiper/css/effect-coverflow';
```

Trying different imports also seem to have no effect on their DOM nodes:

```js
import 'swiper/bundle';  // This applies coverflow styling :)
import 'swiper/css';  // Doesn't seem to do anything when bundle is loaded.
import 'swiper/css/effect-coverflow';  // Nope
import 'swiper/element/css/effect-coverflow';  // Still no
import 'swiper/css/pagination';  // No
import 'swiper/element/css/pagination'; // Too bad
```

- What is the correct way of loading styles in Swiper?
- How do I properly apply the minimal styling of the components?
- Why don't the non bundle style import have any effect?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Swiper v11 element version

I also encountered the same problem

I found that the Swiper CSS style introduced in the project cannot be applied to #shadow-root

document explains how to inject styles [Injecting Styles](https://swiperjs.com/element#injecting-styles)

```
public swiperOptions: SwiperOptions = {
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 5,
  allowTouchMove: true,
  modules: [Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation],
  pagination: {
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: true,
    hideOnClick: false,
  },
  injectStylesUrls: [
    'styles.css'
  ]
}
```

This will apply the global style to #shadoww-root

supplement：

tmd I'm a bit confused

I have only found a way to inject globally packaged CSS files now.

I think this is ridiculous. I think it's best to

`node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination.min.css`

Perform precise injection, but I don't know how to write in the development environment to find the specified directory. If anyone knows, please reply. Thank you~

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35339180)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I imported `swiper-bundle.css` from Swiper. It solved the problem.

```
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
```